# Anybody know what game this belongs to

Tags: identify-this-game

[image]

Any body have any guesses to which game these belong .... most likely a card/dice combo

Comment: The dice have just those 3 colors? Also if it is 3 colors are the same colors on opposite sides?

Comment: Yes just those three and yes they are opposite sides from one another

Answer (score 5):

It took me a while to recognize the dice, but I think they are from a Jenga-like game that I played when I was younger (20-25 years ago). It was called Timber, but I have a hard time finding pictures of it, the best I could do was this:

[image]

I can only find local (I'm from the Netherlands) references to the game, for example the [Dutch wikipedia for Jenga](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenga) mentions the following:

> Een variant van dit spel is "Timber", waarbij de toren bestaat uit lagen van rode, gele en blauwe blokken. Hierbij dient telkens een kleur te worden gegooid met een dobbelsteen en mag alleen een blok van de gegooide kleur uit een willekeurige laag worden gepakt.

Which translates to:

> A variation of this game is "Timber", where the tower is made up from layers of red, yellow and blue blocks. A dice is thrown every turn, resulting in a color and you can only remove a block of that color from an arbitrary layer.

The [Dutch wikipedia on dice](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobbelsteen) also mentions this version of the game and the dice, stating the following:

> In de Jenga-variant Timber wordt een dobbelsteen met kleuren gebruikt. De kleuren zijn rood, blauw en geel, twee van elk.

Which translates to:

> In the Jenga variation Timber, a colured die is used. The colors are red, blue and yellow, two sides of each.

And from memory I recall that game using these dice. I don't think you necessarily need to stack the blocks like in the picture, I thought it could also be alternating layers of red, yellow and blue blocks.

EDIT: I also found the game on [boardgamegeek.com](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/20153/klumpeduns) and it would be called Klumpeduns, only thing is that the dice on that link don't exactly match the dice in your picture.

Comment: The multicolored version is (well, at least used to be) common in Finland. The BGG page has pics of the Finnish edition. In that one, the tower was built so that each level contained one each of red, yellow and blue in the start.

Answer (score 1):

In the United States, the game is called Rainbow Jumbling Tower, a Jenga-like game with red, blue, and yellow blocks. On your turn, you roll the die and then must remove a block in the matching color. You lose if the tower falls over. The last person still in the game wins.

[image]

The game is given various names by market but most seem to be produced by a company named Cardinal Industries. Cardinal is now a part of Spin Master Games, a Canadian company.